# Aligning HTML controls at not happening despite having same LEFT point...?

Tags: html, alignment

How these two controls line up with each other without having to add any more div's?? I've set them both at Left:140px but they still don't align.

```
<pre>
<span id="l4" disabled="disabled" style="display:inline-block;font-family:Arial;font-size:9pt;font-weight:bold;width:117px;">date</span><input 
name="date?4" type="text" value="1/1/2011 12:00:00 AM" id="date?4" runat="server" style="border-color:Black;font-family:Arial;width:300px;left: 140px" />

</br></br>

<span style="font-family: Arial; left: 140px;position: relative;"><input id="chkAll?5" type="checkbox" name="chkAll?5"/>
<label for="chkAll?5">Select All</label></span>
<div id="divChkLst?5" 
style="left:140px;width:300px;height:125px;position:relative;display:block;border-style:solid;border-width:thin;margin:0;border-color:Black;padding:0;

overflow:auto;">
        <table id="pMultiValueList?5" border="0" style="font-family: Arial;">
        <tr>
            <td><span pTag="ReportParameter5"><input id="pMultiValueList?5_0" type="checkbox" name="pMultiValueList?5$0" checked="checked" 

/><label for="pMultiValueList?5_0">qw</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span pTag="ReportParameter5"><input id="pMultiValueList?5_1" type="checkbox" name="pMultiValueList?5$1" checked="checked" 

/><label for="pMultiValueList?5_1">as</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span pTag="ReportParameter5"><input id="pMultiValueList?5_2" type="checkbox" name="pMultiValueList?5$2" checked="checked" 

/><label for="pMultiValueList?5_2">zx</label></span></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><span pTag="ReportParameter5"><input id="pMultiValueList?5_3" type="checkbox" name="pMultiValueList?5$3" /><label 

for="pMultiValueList?5_3">er</label></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div></br></br>
</pre>
```

Comment: Please put the code back... I was still reading it and have to append my answer as appropriate...

Comment: Don't replace `<` with `[` — use the "This is code button" in the editor (or indent by 4 spaces)

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the left attribute on relatively positioned elements. (Well, you *can* but it won't have any effect.) One option is to set

```
 position:absolute;
```

But you will have to actually position them absolutely, and set a top/bottom value.

Edit:

As mentioned below in the comments, you could offset the left values appropriately, if you put them both at 140px and they were not aligned to begin with, they will still be off by the same number of pixels.

Comment: You can and it will have an effect — it will shift the element that number of pixels from where it would have been rendered if it was statically positioned.

Comment: Yeah I think I'll leave it as is for now. This is a dynamically created list of controls and I would have to do all kinds of calculations to do Absolute positioning.